# Selenium invalid argument: invalid 'sameSite'

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

I am trying to login to the facebook with my cookie

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

import time
import datetime
import re
import json

USER_AGENT = "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100065441650865:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML%2C like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % USER_AGENT)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
cook_raw = """[{"name":"datr","value":"9LxhYGI0ori9e12XN2gNvghz","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null},{"name":"fr","value":"1AA4osPKCX9nJGX7c.AWUXi6QDYFGgk4QoYxIHSh36ptM.BgYbz0.pZ.AAA.0.0.BgYb0y.AWUfR3NDQZo","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null},{"name":"xs","value":"15%3AU3H1Bw-UVoF8Zg%3A2%3A1617018175%3A-1%3A-1","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null},{"name":"m_pixel_ratio","value":"1","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":false,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null},{"name":"c_user","value":"100065441650865","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":false,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null},{"name":"sb","value":"9LxhYIx_hHCUfV4psw4KDoRB","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null},{"name":"wd","value":"1080x1920","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":false,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null},{"name":"x-referer","value":"eyJyIjoiL2VudGVyY29kZS5waHA%2FY3A9Y2hhbGRlZXYxazRuJTQwbWFpbC5ydSZzb3VyY2VfdmVyaWZpZWQ9bV9zZXR0aW5ncyZyZWRpcmVjdF90b191bmlmaWVkX2NvbnRhY3Rfc2V0dGluZ19wYWdlIiwiaCI6Ii9lbnRlcmNvZGUucGhwP2NwPWNoYWxkZWV2MWs0biU0MG1haWwucnUmc291cmNlX3ZlcmlmaWVkPW1fc2V0dGluZ3MmcmVkaXJlY3RfdG9fdW5pZmllZF9jb250YWN0X3NldHRpbmdfcGFnZSIsInMiOiJtIn0%3D","domain":".facebook.com","hostOnly":false,"path":"/","secure":true,"httpOnly":false,"sameSite":"no_restriction","session":true,"firstPartyDomain":"","storeId":null}]"""
cookie_dict = json.loads(cook_raw)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
driver.add_cookie(cookie_dict[0])
```

I have an error

> InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid 'sameSite'

How can I fix the error?

**UPDATE**

I added `cook = cookie_dict[0].pop('sameSite')`
But received an error > Message: invalid argument: missing 'cookie'

Comment: that attribute is probably optional.  Try removing it.

Comment: (just a reminder: remember not to post your actual "remember me" type cookie(s) here...)